# LaTeX: is it possible to create a macro to add words to index (using TexMaker)?

Tags: macros, indexing, texmaker

I'm just finishing my first document (a book), and I have to create an index (`\makeindex`, `\printindex`, `\index{WORD}`, ...).

I am using TexMaker on Linux.

I was wondering if it's possible to define something like a "macro", to be able to avoid adding `\index{WORD}` before each word to be indexed (my document will have *very* many words to be indexed... :-).

I mean, I'd like to be able to define a command which would allow me - clicking a keyboard short-cut, for example `[Ctrl][F9]` - to insert `\index{WORD}` just before the WORD the cursor is on...

Skimming through *TexMaker* docs, I couldn't find anything useful to that intent...

**UPDATE**
I am following the suggestions in the comments, but I can't yet fully understand how to solve my problem... Feel quite dumb right now... :-(

So: I add the command `\iindex` in my book heading, as Sigur suggested:

```
\newcommand\iindex[1]{#1\index{#1}}
```

So far so good. Now I would like to associate a keyboard shortcut to it.
As suggested (always by Sigur) I look for a *macros* menu, but I can't find it (I use Texmaker 4.0.3).
As suggested by Aradnix, I open the User menu, and find these sub-menus:

- User Tags
- User Commands
- Customize Completion

Both Tags, Commands can be customized, but I suppose:
  - Commands are for external commands (not my case).
  - Tags are more promising, but what do I write in tag's LaTeX content? I mean, how do I refer to the word under cursor, which I want to index?
  - Customize completion lists items already defined (which include for example `\index{•}`), and I can add new commands; but, I can't understand how to associate it with a shortcut... :-).

Any more *literal* suggestion for a LaTeX newbe...?
If anybody solves and answers, I *will* accept the answer, of course... :-)

Comment: First, I suggest you to define a new command `\newcommand\iindex[1]{#1\index{#1}}`. then you can add a shortcut to this command and then you double click a word and press the shortcut. I guess that this should work.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose you added an excess "i"...: "\newcommand\index[1]{#1\index{#1}}", right? And, sorry (I told I was new to LaTeX? :-), how do I add a shortcut to a command?

Comment: No! `\index` already exists. So I defined a new command, so you can not use the same name. The new command makes use of the old one.

Comment: I see, sorry...

Comment: How do I add a shortcut to a command, in Texmaker?

Comment: I think one if the fancier index packages (I don't remember which) comes with a macro that does what @Sigur's `\iindex` does - puts its argument in the text and the index.

Comment: I use TeXstudio. It is similar. First, insert the new command in your preamble. Then, use the Macros menu to add a new macro. You can call it as you wish and use the new command on the macro, that is, the result of the macro will be `\iindex{foo}`. After this you can access the macro in the same menu or you can use the shortcut. In my editor, `shift+F1`. Then, select the word and press it.

Comment: Hi @MarcoS is very easy to create shortcuts and customize things in TeXmaker as in TeXStudio as @Sigur says (in fact, TeXStudio is a fork from TeXMaker). In the `user` menu you can add and custom tags, commands or improve the autocompletation. For me is the easiest way to do what you want.

Comment: I did just update the OP...

Comment: `\newcommand{\iindex}[2][]{\index{#1#2}#2}` would be better; `\index` should go before the indexed word, and one could call it like `\iindex[xyz@]{$xyz$}` so calling `\index{xyz@$xyz$}` for sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having added the suggested `\newcommand` to the preamble, you can add a user tag with

```
\iindex{@}
```

as 'LaTeX Content'. Using the default shortcut, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> if the first tag was chosen, will insert `\iindex{•}`, or if a word was selected, it will replace `word` with `\iindex{word}`.

I don't know if it is possible to change these shortcuts, I didn't see anything in Options --> Configure Texmaker --> Shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks! I could add my first item to index with a key! Is there some way to change the shortcut (from default [shift][F1]) to something else?

Comment: @MarcoS As I said, I don't know. Some shortcuts can be modified in the options, but these are not listed.

Comment: Anybody? Really Texmaker doesn't allow to change tags shortcuts??? I can even change some config file, if GUI does not allow it...

Comment: @MarcoS Texmaker isn't the most configurable editor I think. TeXstudio, mentioned in the comments to your question, does let you change these.

Comment: I will try TeXstudio ASAP... :-)