# Add index item by macro

Tags: macros, indexing

I am struggling with creating a macro that would enable me to create index items by macro. From a former post ([LaTeX: is it possible to create a macro to add words to index (using TexMaker)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151379/latex-is-it-possible-to-create-a-macro-to-add-words-to-index-using-texmaker/183261#183261)) I have tried to use the following, but I can't get it to work. 
I am using TexmMakerX on Mac (home) and Windows (work).

I have added

```
\newcommand\iindex[1]{#1\index{#1}}
```

to my preamble. I also added the same line to User -> User Macros, but the macro would only print `\newcommand\iindex[1]{#1\index{#1}}` on the screen. Also `\iindex` would not work. I can't figure out how to use this macro... Ideally I'd like it to highlight a word and insert `\index{WORD}` right before that word.

I am obviously not a LaTeX pro... and I would really appreciate a hint...

---

Edit/Comment:

Thanks alls for your kind answers - sorry for forgetting the MWE. Indexing is working fine generally. All commands in my preamble are working without problems.

I have a large document without index, and I want to add an index to it. Since it is really tedious to copy each word that I want to index, then type \index{PASTE} and continue I am looking for a semi-automatic method. 
In AucTeX on Emacs you could position the cursor within a word and hit a key to index it, but I don't use either one any more. I was trying to achieve sopmething liek this in TexMakerX by combining the `\newcommand` from the first post above with a TexMakerX makro.

I like the Andrew's suggestion below, but would prefer highlighting a word and indexing it with a keystroke...

Thanks to all, it would be cool if you had an idea to help me.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: after your definition you should be able to use `\iindex{WORD}` to typeset WORD and add it to the index. However your question appears not to be about latex at all but about how to highlight WORD and have it replaced by `\iindex{WORD}` . That is purely a function of the editor you are using it is unrelated to the LaTeX system itself, but you have not even said which editor that is.

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't given a MWE it is not clear to me what is not working as this looks fine to me.

Here is something that I have used in the past. In TeX the double quote character is not very useful (as ``life'' is better than "life" in TeX), so when I need an index I redefine the double quotes so that "something" puts `something` in `\textsf` and also adds it to the index.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\catcode`\"=13  % make the double quote character " active
\gdef"#1"{\textsf{#1}\index{#1}} % define "*" to do indexing+\textsf

\begin{document}

Here is "something" that I am "indexing".

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Rather than my fancy quote command what you have should work, so perhaps your problems lie elsewhere?

To produce the index you need:

- `\usepackage{makeidx}` and `\makeindex` in the preamble
- a `\printindex` where you want the index to appear, and,
- you need to run `makeindex` on the `idx` file that `LaTeX` produces.